# Facing very bad performance for angular.copy for large array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, performance, large-data

**[Edit]**

We identified that regex was not the problem but angular.copy. hence I updated the question from RegEx problem to Angular.copy problem.

**[Original]**

I want to change the Name from format "BD12" to "BD" for example, in all the records and I have an array of approx. 3000 records of this object type:

```
{
Name: "BD12",
PostCode: "SE 15477 28954",
State_Id: 2,
State: null,
Country_Id: 2,
Country: "United Kingdom",
GridReference: null,
Region: null,
AreaCode: "01274",
Latitude: 53.75672,
Longitude: -1.7667413,
Easting: 415477,
Northing: 428954,
Id: 2
}
```

I am doing this computation with Array.map function and it takes about 30 seconds to 1 minute on my 64bit Dell Latitude E5540 with 8GB ram Intel CoreI5 2 and 2.6 GHz.

```
data.results = [];//contains [2500] records
$scope.outWardCodes = angular.copy(data.results)
.map(wc=> { wc.Name = wc.Name.match("^[a-zA-Z]+"); return wc }));
```

How to improve this?

**[EDIT]**
I also need the original array.

Comment: can you tell us how long it takes to do `angular.copy(data.results)`? and how much improvement you make by replacing it with `data.results.slice(0)`?

Comment: oh Angularrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr. It was taking all the time 2 minutes and 48 seconds now when I tested, for angular.copy(data.results). the map function takes only some mili seconds. The second problem is the results were breeze.js objects which has a large number of object traversing references may be that was also the problem. Array.slice takes only millis. :P

Comment: Should I remove the question or edit it?

Comment: Posted this as an answer as it may help someone to take right decision.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
angular.copy(data.results)
```

with

```
data.results.map(function(value){value = Object.create(value);return value});
```

or simply

```
$scope.outWardCodes = data.results.map(function(value){value = Object.create(value); value.Name = value.Name.match("^[a-zA-Z]+"); return value});
```

Comment: No wait! I need a copy. I want to remove the reference to old array. This 'slice' still keeps the reference to the old array and hence editing affects that too.

Comment: Nope slice returns new Array

Comment: check this in chrome. 
var aa = [{name:"aa"}];
var bb = aa.slice(0);
bb[0].name="bb";
console.log(aa[0]);

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch try the updated code and let me know the performance

Comment: I think the answer and the question's context has changed.. and old loop solution for the problem, though works ;)